# Why is $(20<-60^{\circ})$ = $(10-j17.32)$?

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers

I'm browsing my engineering mathematics book and saw this in a solution under determinant of a $2x$ matrix:

> $(20<-60^{\circ})$ = $(10-j17.32)$

How did this happen?  I know that $j$ stands for $\sqrt{-1}$ because $i$ is the symbol for current in engineering. I'm also not so familiar with the modes on my calculator.

Answer (score 3):

This is the complex number whose amplitude is $20$ and which is $60^{\circ}$ below the real axis.
The components are $20\cos(-60)^{\circ}$ and $20\sin(-60)^{\circ}$